# Subset Pandas dataframe columns conditionally on a row value referenced by label via isin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame in a wide format. I want to subset the columns based on a comparison of a row's value with a list (and I want to refer to that row by its label).

For example consider the following data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

y = pd.DataFrame({'one': pd.Series(random.sample(range(100), 5), index=list('abcde')),
                 'two': pd.Series(random.sample(range(100), 5),
                 index=list('abcde')),
                 'three': pd.Series(list('ABCDE'), index=list('abcde'))})
```

> ```
>    one three  two
> a   76     A   94
> b   46     B   36
> c   28     C   86
> d   83     D   17
> e   15     E   98
> ```

I have a set of values to be used for comparison:

```
myset = {83, 17}
```

Now, let's say I want a data frame where we have all rows but only the columns where row `'d'` has a value in `myset`.

My desired result would be:

> ```
>    one two
> a   76 94
> b   46 36
> c   28 86
> d   83 17
> e   15 98
> ```

However, I'm having trouble extracting that, based on the row label and values in the set.

This gives an appropriate boolean vector:

```
y.loc['d'].isin(myset)
```

However, I'm unable to subset the way I'd expect to with that boolean, e.g.

```
y.iloc[:,y.loc['d'].isin(myset)]
```

> ValueError: iLocation based boolean indexing cannot use an indexable
>   as a mask

***Clarification:*** An important criterion of this question is that I'm only comparing the row of interest (row "d" in the example above) against `myset`. I don't care if other rows have values in `myset` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to get the mask, then `.loc`:

```
y.loc[:, y.apply(lambda col: col.d in myset)]
```

Output:

```
   one  two
a   76   94
b   46   36
c   28   86
d   83   17
e   15   98
```

Comment: A better use case for your example would be where one of the numeric columns matches and the other doesn't, e.g. `myset = {83, 16}`

Comment: @andrew_reece Great answer!  +1 I had nearly the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or we using `replace` and `isnull`

```
df.loc[:,df.replace(dict(zip(list(myset), [np.nan]*len(myset)))).isnull().any().values]
Out[907]: 
   one  two
a   76   94
b   46   36
c   28   86
d   83   17
e   15   98
```

Edit :

```
df.loc[:,df.loc[['d']].replace(dict(zip(list(myset), [np.nan]*len(myset)))).isnull().any().values]
```

Comment: @Hack-R sorry misunderstanding the question , check the edit